# How to catch ALL exceptions that are thrown in Symfony 4 (including those thrown in console, phpunit, bad configuration etc.)

Tags: php, exception, symfony4

Symfony 4 throws many kind of exceptions. For example: console command exceptions, bad YAML configuration exceptions (appear in console also), exceptions during the request etc.
Unfortunately not all of them can be catched via documented solution:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-exception
None of console exceptions fire kernel.exception event.

I'm trying this with Symfony 4.2.*

I've come up with ugly solution, where I override one of Kernel class methods (Kernel.php).
But documentation doesn't say anything about this solution, and I wonder is there a better way to catch ALL exceptions, and log them using Monolog.

```php
    /**
     * @throws \Throwable
     */
    protected function initializeContainer() {

        try {
            $container = parent::initializeContainer();
        } catch (\Throwable $throwable){
            // here i can handle those exceptions/errors
            $this->logCriticalErrors($throwable);
            throw $throwable;
        }
        return $container;
    }
```

I expect to catch and log ALL possibly thrown exceptions including: errors in YAML configuration of any installed bundle, exceptions thrown directly in PHPUnit tests etc. in one file.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html Use Kernel events

Comment: You could also use [set_exception_handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php) - but this wont generally allow you to recover from the error.  *"Sets the default exception handler if an exception is not caught within a try/catch block. Execution will stop after the exception_handler is called"*  It will allow you to log it though.  You can also combine this with [set_error_handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) by throwing an exception for uncaught errors, then catching it with the exception handler.

Comment: @Lulceltech you didn't read my post. I used Kernel events before.